# Using Thinktecture IdentityServer with Two-level authentication IIS 7/Integrated

Tags: authentication, iis-7.5, forms-authentication, windows-authentication, thinktecture-ident-server

Has anyone successfully implemented two-level authentication using thinktecture identity server running under IIS 7.5?

The solutions I've tried all seem to be geared toward IIS 6/classic mode, I did find one guy that seemed to have tackled the problem at:

http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/

Though not having much luck getting it to play with Thinktecture.

What we're trying to do is authenticate the user through Windows Authentication, and if that's not available, then send them to the forms authentication.  I'm not sure why this is so complicated, seems like it would be a common task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really supported in ASP.NET (the authenticationMode attribute in web.config is an enum for a good reason - either Windows or Forms). This is a limitation of IIS/ASP.NET.

All approaches (like the one from Mike) are considered "hacks". They might work - but the ASP.NET app on top must be designed for it/aware of it. IdentityServer isn't.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions how to get this functionality working with IdentityServer?  Or am I basically going to have to install it twice, once inside the domain and once outside?

Comment: Well - some use a vdir that is set to Windows - set the session cookie there and redirect to the main app. Also not perfect but works. You'd need to replicate IdSrv cookie setter there of course. (or in other words - it is not supported by ASP.NET ;))